# How to configure Java Kerberos in sqljdbc4.jar

Tags: java, jdbc, kerberos

Could anyone explain to me how to configure Java Kerberos by using sqljdbc4.jar?
Because I'm getting an error second time I run my application, the error displayed `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed`.

**(NOTE- Error Displaying occurs only For servlet Projects. I'm using apache tomcat)**

There is a tutorial [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/) about Kerberos. But I don't understand how to include it in my cording.

```java
public Connection Get_connection(PrintWriter out) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName = Colombo_Health; integratedSecurity=true; authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
        out.println("Connection Established");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        out.println("Class not Found       " + e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("Driver not Found    " + e.toString());
    }

    return con;
}
```

1. I'm on Windows 10 with SQL Server 2014.
2. I have copied `sqljdbc_auth.dll` to system 32

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the amount of information you have provided, I think the error lies in not setting your connection's properties. Add `con.setServerName(value)` and `con.setDatabaseName(value)`  along with these [Other Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988(v=sql.110).aspx) that may apply

Comment: when i run firs time it is working without error since i change coding. after changing i have to restart net-beans in order to run the application.

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the wrong *authenticationScheme*. By specifying *JavaKerberos* you tell the client to use the Java implementation of Kerberos. If you want to use *sqljdbc_auth.dll* for authentication, you should be using *NativeAuthentication* as your authentication scheme.